# Поведение memcpy в MinGW

Tags: c, mingw

Здравствуйте, ХэшКодовцы!

Продолжаем осваивать `C`. Использую для компиляции MinGW, есть в нем, как и многих других, функция `memcpy` из `string.h`. Есть вот такой код:

```
#define MAX_LIST_SIZE 132
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte *src = (byte *) malloc (MAX_LIST_SIZE * sizeof(byte));
byte length = 255;

byte dst[MAX_LIST_SIZE];

memcpy(&(dst[0]), src, length);
```

Т.е. как я понимаю, должна быть хоть какая-то ошибка, но программа успешно завершается. Или я не совсем правильно понимаю, как работает сия конструкция? Если в `memcpy` есть какая-то защита, можно ли ее отключить?

**UPD**

Я уже до этого писал два вопроса о разборе кода, точнее о его проверке. Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать некоторый фреймворк, чтобы тестировать функции. В коде есть такая конструкция, а на платформе, которая нам недоступна (это один из ARM процессоров), такая ошибка будет фатальной. Вот хочется как-то в фреймворке наиболее приблизиться к поведению, которое может быть на платформе.

Я думал, что в данном коде, а именно в функции `memcpy` мы как минимум дважды выходим за границы массива (т.к. оба массива = 132 байта). Более того, я думаю, что и стек мы бы задевали, так как пытаемся скопировать на 123 байта больше, чем нужно и так далее.

Comment: Если dst глобальный массив (объявлен вне функций), то ошибка скорее всего произойдет в случае, когда length превысит размер секции данных. Попробуйте задать значение length побольше:) Если же dst локальный массив, то для вылета с ошибкой обычно достаточно затереть адрес возврата из функции, для этого нужно где-то лишних байт 8.

Comment: Ну тут 123 байта. Но какой ошибки ждёт @Dex? Это C, работа идёт на низком уровне и многие бяки никак не диагностируются.

Comment: смотрите UPD

Comment: Что касается malloc, посмотрите electric-fence. Или DUMA

Comment: @alexlz, `malloc` тут не при делах. Интересует только `memcpy`.

Comment: @Dex, ИМХО как раз memcpy НЕ ОБЯЗАН заниматься ничем кроме собственно копирования. А о том чтобы он не копировал что-то не туда куда надо должен по идее заботиться программист.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакой защиты в `memcpy` - если размер массива будет больше таргета то вы спокойно затрете соседнюю область памяти, а что там будет лежать одному аллаху ведомо. В лучшем случае поменяется значение какого-нибудь мусора, а среднем случае важной переменной, в тяжелом случае завалите ось к чертям.

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Кроме определения тяжелого и среднего случаев. IMHO наоборот.

--

@Dex, используя memcpy() о массивах (и их границах) думает  **только программист**. На самом деле, функция просто пересылает n байт с одного адреса на другой, даже не задумываясь об возможном перекрытии областей источника и приемника.

Comment: @avp ну я в комментарии к предыдущему ответу уже рецепт давал. Правда в виндах это требует (если я правильно понял) переименования всех этих malloc'ов (поскольку нет LD_PRELOAD), но уж тут...

Comment: Интересно, как можно в современных ОС, с системой виртуальной памяти и разными режимами привелегий, завалить систему записью по какому-нибудь адресу ?

Comment: @mikillskegg Если этот код будет в длл, которая аттачится к разным процессам - то легко!

Comment: @mikillskegg, не думаю, что во всех ARM процессорах есть то, что есть в современных ОС. Вопрос состоял несколько в ином, как отследить и быть уверенным, что оно будет переписано, запуская этот код на ОС, например, Windows?

@Barmaley, спасибо.

Comment: @Dex С архитектурой ARM есть и весьма скромные по размерам ROM/RAM микроконтроллеры (десятки килобайт). По крайней мере ARM7.
@shurik, а кто такая длл, которая аттачится к разным процессам?

Comment: @alexlz - эта та длл которая используется в разных процессах, можно "насильно" заставить процесс использовать эту длл, например поставив хук.

Comment: @ahurik Ну этого я всё равно не пойму. Мне что хук, что апперкот... Ломиком лучше.